# Braintree-javascript - How to charge users monthly based on usage?

Tags: javascript, braintree

After thoroughly searching through the [documentation](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/overview) for a plan based on usage, I am stumped on how I can charge my user monthly based on usage of my app.

For example, customers of my app would post listings. Each listing has a button that other users can click. I want to charge my customer monthly and based on the number of clicks on customer's listing's button. The more clicks on the listing's button, the greater the amount charged. If nobody clicked on the button in that month, then the monthly bill would be 0.

Since I will be charging my customer monthly, I think this would go under 'Recurring Billing'.

The current work around I have in my head is to create a plan with a cost of 0 that user would subscribe to. Then at the end of each month, based off the number of clicks on button (which I keep track of), I would update the subscription's price.

Would this work?

If so, is there a better way to do this?

If not, how should I implement this billing behavior?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full Disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

[Recurring Billing](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/overview) is better suited for charging users on a monthly subscription basis with a relatively stable price. You may encounter difficulty because you cannot [update the price of a subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/manage/#updating-subscriptions) that is past due. There are also rules about when you can change the price of a subscription if you are based in the EU. There *are* mechanisms to increment a subscription price called [add-ons](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans#add-ons-and-discounts), but again this is not the usage they were intended for.
​

Since you are already planning to track clicks and update the subscription price on a monthly basis, I recommend simply calculating the price you would like to charge the customer and [generating a basic transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/node) with that amount rather than using subscriptions with the Recurring Billing feature.

​
I hope this helps. If you have questions about this or any other details about your specific integration, I recommend reaching out to the [Braintree support team](https://www.support.braintreepayments.com) to discuss your options. 
​

Comment: hi is it possible to charge the client automatically in the background with only one consent? some user told me I can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006254/is-it-possible-to-make-automation-payment-with-paypal-or-stripe