# is it possible to make automation payment with paypal or stripe

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment

I am looking for a solution in Paypal API
which is when the client connects his account with my platform the PayPal will draw as much money as he uses the platform, however after research, I find a subscription option that can cycle every day but with a fixed price. and another option is to create invoices after a period of time.

so my question is there a way for my client to pay as his use with one consent from PayPal or any other platform like stripe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Stripe or Braintree with cron jobs

Comment: but can it draw money [not fixed price between 5 or more] from the client without his interaction, like in the background?

Comment: Yes.  Must save payment method

Answer (score 0):

after more research, I think there's no way for a client on any platform like stripe or PayPal to charge them on the background with one consent, 
however, there's a way but looks like hack around this problem, which is tell the client to create an app on Paypal and use that app conditional on payout API :/